# Canon MX320 printer doesn't print any more

Tags: printing, canon, restore

I have Canon Pixma MX320 printer, that used to print ok in Ubuntu 12.04...after I uninstalled KDE Plasma (I made back up before that) it stopped working...I suppose I uninstalled canon drivers...is it possible to restore just appropriate canon drivers or should I install them again (I forgot the procedure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu you not needed to care on drivers for printers. Just got to setting > printers and add a new. Ubuntu finds your printer.

It must be plugged in via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get install cups* printer-driver-cjet printer-driver*`. 
This should install most of the available drivers...

#### Disclaimer-type thing:

If you computer has Nvidia graphics , you might not want to run this, as I noticed it seemed to be installing alot of `nvidia*` packages... This seems to be related to these packages: `libcupti-dev libcupti5.0`